# SeleniumQuery i.e. $.driver().get().navigate().to(url) is not waiting page to load completely

Tags: selenium

We are using Seleniumquery-0.19.0 for our selenium tests.

we noticed that $.url() is not waiting for page to load completely. I also tried $.driver().get().navigate().to(url);.

our Scenario,

1. open the page.
2. search for login controls i.e user and password text box
3. fill value and click on submit button.

In the test result we found that selenium is not able to find the Username text box. we tried with

1. waits i.e.  $("*[id='login.username']").waitUntil(5000).isPresent();
2. timeouts i.e.  $.driver().get().manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
3. static void waitForPageLoad(final WebDriver wdriver) {
       final WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(wdriver, 600);

   ```
   final Function<WebDriver, Boolean> pageLoaded = new Function<WebDriver, Boolean>() {

       @Override
       public Boolean apply(final WebDriver input) {
           final Boolean result =
               ((JavascriptExecutor)input).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
           LOG.info("Status of the Page : " + result);

           return result;
       }
   };

   wait.until(pageLoaded);
   ```

   }

Comment: do you have a Single Page App which is loading it's content through ajax?

Comment: No, its not a SPA.

Comment: ok. I have tested your selector with the waituntil() line and it works for my code. Can you provide more html code?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Thread.sleep(ms)` after navigating to the URL.

Comment: Thanks for you response, but we have figured out the problem, actually our test environment was setup in aws and any how the tomcat is getting restarted. so we have fixed the issue by changing the aws config.